# Itext and PngImage

Tags: java, itext

I have a java application which usesitext for generating reports.
I have to include a logo which is in a resolution of 150dpi.
The code I uwrote is the following:

```
final float logoWidth = 368;
final float logoHeigth = 182;
float x = PageSize.A4.getWidth() - (16 * millimeters) - logoWidth;
float y = PageSize.A4.getHeight() - logoHeigth;    

final InputStream idLogo = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/logos/ID_Module_150dpi_layoutgroesse.png");

Image logoTop = PngImage.getImage(idLogo);
logoTop.setAbsolutePosition(x, y);
```

The problem is that the logo is added at the right position but the size is not correct. It is twice the height and twice the width. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried scaleToFit()

```
Image logoTop = PngImage.getImage(idLogo);
logoTop.scaleToFit(x, y);
```

And then positioning it, personally I use `scaleToFit()` combined with tables in iText to position

Comment: Well, in between I found that If an image is placed without any scaling the the resolution will be 72. If an image is placed with a scaling of 50% the the resolution will be 144. With lower scalings the resolution will increase because the pixels are the same but the size will be smaller.  In my case I have to scale to 45% because the desired resolution is 150 DPI. I am using logoTop.scalePercent(48)

Comment: Oh ok, very interesting, glad you found an answer!

Comment: BTW, I have to scale it to 48% and NOT to 45%. My fault.